# Why doesn't the cursor stay at the same place?

Tags: function, dictionary, vim, text-cursor

I have a very strange problem which I can't resolve after trying the whole morning.

This is my function and mapping:

```
nnoremap ,zz :call SwapAW("2-2","5")<CR>
nnoremap ,zc :call SwapAW("2-2","5")<CR> 


function! SwapAW(keyw,number)
  let li = line('.')
  let co = col('.')  

 exe "call cursor(li,co)" 
 let linew= line('.')
 let conew= col('.')
 echo linew conew
endfunction
```

,zc --> moves the cursor to the right
,zz --> the cursor stays where it is

I changed everything but can't find out why the cursor doesn't stay where it is in both cases.
I changed p.e. the mapping, from ,zc to ,zd and ,zz to ,zw  (tried others as well) and changed the leaderkey from `,` to `\`, and tried to swap both mapping lines.
Nothing changes. 
What's happening?
What did I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You have a trailing `<Space>` character in your `,zc` mapping (after the `<CR>`). *That* moves the cursor after the function invocation.

With mappings, one must be careful with hidden characters. Therefore, it's advisable (and sometimes, e.g. at the beginning of a mapping, necessary) to literally write the special form `<Space>` when you actually need to include one.

---

My [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966) will highlight those trailing spaces and tabs, as many code guidelines frown on them. The plugin page also contains links to alternatives.

Comment: +1 for the heroic spot. I haven't used the plugin but `set list` is another option to easily show trailing spaces (more on this in [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_unwanted_spaces)).

Comment: thank you. I thought that space after <CR> had no influence on the exec.

Comment: @gokcehan Trailing whitespaces are the only normal way to live with `fo=a` and have good (= right and predictable paragraph detection) reformatting with `gq` which is convenient for the text in comments and documentation. Using `set list lcs+=trail:-` is not intrusive and shows you trailing whitespaces, this plugin cannot possibly be the same as the only way to highlight space with `matchadd()` is changing background color and this is either intrusive (like ctermbg=Red) or easy to miss. Ignoring `list` highlight is easier then cofiguring plugin to ignore whitespaces under this circumstances.

Comment: Among other things I have in a `BufWritePre` autocmd `:call` site is `%s/\s\+$//e`.  I do not do this autocmd on .txt files for exactly the reason @ZyX mentions.  :)

Comment: @Remonn: Inside the command-line, spaces indeed are harmless; but remember that after the `<CR>`, you're back to normal mode, and there `<Space>` is an actual movement command.

Comment: This just made me completely rethink how I've been working with mappings.  The things that I could have missed; the problems that I've encountered without solutions...